# Efficient signal handling

Tags: c++, signals

I’ve got a c++ program that takes as command line arguments paths to some files and then does some number crunching. There is no further user input, but the program might output some stuff on stdout.
I’m wondering now how to implement signal handling for this program. The program will end, no matter what signal is received, but the main signals will be SIGINT if the user interrupts the program or SIGALRM if some timeout is reached. However, I need to print some sort of summary to stdout before exiting the program.

As I’m new to c++ (coming from c#/java), I’m wondering how to do this most efficiently. I’ve read the documentation and if I understood it correctly, I’m not allowed to print anything to stdout within the signal handler. The standard way I’ve came across during research was to set a flag and check that flag constantly. However, I don’t quite like this approach, as this would introduce many additional conditional jumps.

I know, premature optimization is the root of all evil. And sure enough, I might end up implementing the flag approach anyway but since I’m new to c++, I’m wondering if there is a different approach that I’m unaware of. I thought about spawning a new thread that does the calculations and using sigwait in the main thread to wait for signals and if one is received, print the summary, and exit the process.

Is there some better way?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: 1. You *can* print from a signal handler - just need to ensure you're not calling anything that's not async-signal-safe. 2. Why are you worried about "conditional jumps"? The program is about to exit. So what's the efficiency issue here? 3. sigwait approach is fine. But this is usually done if there are multiple threads already. If your program is single-threaded, there's no point in having a separate thread handle the signals.

Comment: Thanks for the info. ad 1: as I’m reading from files and also printing during the program, I came to the conclusion that I can’t print from the signal handler. ad 2: the jump would be from the check to the flag that I need to put throughout the program. Something like if (flag) {//Print summary and exit}. Thus this check would occur countless times through the program.

Comment: ad 3: I know, and I would like to do it without an additional thread, but I cannot find another way that does it without the flag. Of course, creating an additional thread will come with significant overhead, but it is constant whereas the check to the flag will induce linear cost in the runtime of the program.

Comment: @P.P: The concept of `async-signal-safe` is a POSIX concept, but POSIX has no C++ binding. C++ itself does not define `async-signal-safe`. C++ has a _very_ limited list of things that are safe, and `std::cout` is **not** on that list, nor is `std::printf`. You **can't** print from a signal handler.

Comment: Note that `sigwait` is a POSIX function, not a portable C++ function. There's a good chance that it will still work; the C and C++ threading and memory models are intentionally identical.

Comment: What actaully takes the most time, reading the input file[s], writing the results out to the output file[s] or computation in between? If the I/O is what's taking the most time, then you can check whether your program was signaled at every I/O function, which won't affect the overall performance measurably.

Comment: Reading the files will only be done at the beginning, from then on everything is done in memory. Thus, this should only take a small amount of time. No output files are written but output will be printed to stdout throught the program. Depending on the input, this can happen not at all or basically all the time. So the computation in between will take the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @MSalters Printing by different means (other than std::cout and std::printf) isn't prohibited by C++, though. Nor does it make it invalid to use sigwait or any other POSIX function in C++. It simply means it's outside the scope of C++ standard - not "you are not allowed to do anything not defined by C++ standard".